# Finding dependencies of a compiled library on Unix

Tags: c, linux, linker

Is there a way to find names of libraries that a given library depends on?

Basically I have an ".so" file that I load dynamically, and I know all the other .so files that it's going to try to load

**Update 07/07**:
I found /proc//maps pretty useful, it gives locations of loaded dynamic libraries for a given process

Answer (score 0):

Type `readelf -a <PATH-TO-LIBRARY> | grep 'NEEDED'` in your terminal.

Note: `readelf` is part of *binutils*.